# Duplicated Linked Objects and shared Material scaling

Tags: shaders

I found this post that pretty much covers what I am asking about, [Is there some way to map different image textures to instances of linked duplicates?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1075/is-there-some-way-to-map-different-image-textures-to-instances-of-linked-duplica)

but my problem is that I have duplicate objects at different scaling and I want them to all share the same material - but of course that material is rendered at scaling related to the object size, not a consistent size across all of the duplicates.

Short of creating different shaders for each scale size, is there a way (maybe geometry nodes) to have blender formulaically scale material size consistently to duplicated object size?

Here are two duplicated rock objects with the same Shader node, but the scale is different because the object size is different.  I want the shader scale to NOT change across the duplicate scaling.  I thought maybe applying all transforms might help but I can't do that with dups.

Also checked Geometry and Object Info nodes but neither holds scaling/objects size info to be used as a scale factor
[image]

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure whether this is what you want and whether your object have all applied its scale, but if your scale is applied to your objects, you could achieve this with this node setup:

[image]

[image]

It takes the object coordinates and multiplies this with a "scaling" vector (Value node), then you can move your texture with the values of the "Add" node.

With a non-scale-applied object you could use this setup:

GN + shader:

[image]

Geometry nodes provides the scaling attribute to the shader. The shader uses that value to scale the texture appropiately.

result:

[image]

Comment: Hmm, thx Chris for the quick reply  - I started a simple new project but don't get these results, first method has scaling issue in one dimension and second solution just yields a solid dark object.  I've triple checked that my setup is the same. Are you sure no other settings and/or does you object still look good from every angle or is there hidden scaling problems on other side of your object?  I'd share a shot, but I don't that as an option in this comment area.  And I've tried variations of the control values :-)

Comment: Could you pls provide your sample blend file soon can check it out? You can open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions to share blend file

Comment: Ok, you can also provide a link to any cloud storage like Dropbox/google drive or whatever.

Comment: can u pls do me a favor and do File -> External data -> pack resources, save your file and upload again so that i can see your textures? thanks!

Comment: you forgot to provide a new link to your updated file....;)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PqQEYjyvCeejcxk81n_WMQVR3ujAzlln/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey Chris, that link above is the new link

Comment: Hey Chris, that link above is the new link