# Assign different materials to different object copies

Tags: python, materials, scripting, objects, color

I'm trying to create two different copies of an object with different colors. The code below will create them but they always end up with the same color (1,1,0,1) (yellow).
How can I get `new_arrow` to be red and `new_arrow2` to be yellow?
I'm new to scripting in Blender.

```
arrow = D.objects['cyl']
    
new_arrow = arrow.copy()
new_arrow.location = (0,0,2)
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("PKHG")
mat.diffuse_color = (1,0,0,1)
new_arrow.active_material = mat;
C.collection.objects.link(new_arrow)

new_arrow2 = arrow.copy()
new_arrow2.location = (0,2,2)
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("PKHG")
mat.diffuse_color = (1,1,0,1)
new_arrow2.active_material = mat;
C.collection.objects.link(new_arrow2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because `arrow.copy()` only copies the object data-block but not the mesh  data-block that resides inside `arrow.data`. And since the [material is by default linked to the mesh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/613/why-are-materials-linked-to-meshes-by-default), you will end up with an object containing the same mesh and hence the same material. You can change that by either: (1) duplicating the mesh `new_arrow.data = arrow.data.copy()` with this script:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

arrow = D.objects['cyl']

new_arrow = arrow.copy()
new_arrow.data = arrow.data.copy()
new_arrow.location = (0,0,2)
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("PKHG")
mat.diffuse_color = (1,0,0,1)


new_arrow.active_material = mat;
C.collection.objects.link(new_arrow)

new_arrow2 = arrow.copy()
new_arrow2.data = arrow.data.copy()
new_arrow2.location = (0,2,2)
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("PKHG")
mat.diffuse_color = (1,1,0,1)
new_arrow2.active_material = mat;
C.collection.objects.link(new_arrow2)
```

or (2) if you want to have copied objects linked to the same mesh, you can change the behavior of the object to have materials linked to *Object* instead of *Data* using `new_arrow.material_slots[0].link = 'OBJECT'`

[image]

by using this script:

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data

arrow = D.objects['cyl']

new_arrow = arrow.copy()
new_arrow.material_slots[0].link = 'OBJECT'
new_arrow.location = (0,0,2)
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("PKHG")
mat.diffuse_color = (1,0,0,1)
new_arrow.active_material = mat;
C.collection.objects.link(new_arrow)

new_arrow2 = arrow.copy()
new_arrow2.material_slots[0].link = 'OBJECT'
new_arrow2.location = (0,2,2)
mat = bpy.data.materials.new("PKHG")
mat.diffuse_color = (1,1,0,1)
new_arrow2.active_material = mat;
C.collection.objects.link(new_arrow2)
```

Comment: Thanks, new_arrow.data = arrow.data.copy() is just what I needed.