# UV Edit: see multiple UV maps?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have several UV maps on the same mesh [managed separately by different objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/297079/51657), and I'd like to see them all together in the UV Edit window, is this possible?

<sub>I only found this Q: [Arrange UV maps of multiple objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/30668/51657), but [this doesn't work in Blender 3+](https://blenderartists.org/t/uv-editing-draw-other-objects/1296149/2), and anyway I suppose it also wouldn't work for objects with the same mesh (because they have the same UV map in the Viewport preview).</sub>

Comment: You could link duplicate your object, select the first UV map of object 1, select the second UV map of object 2, select both, switch to Edit mode, you'll see the 2 UV maps overlapping?

Comment: @moonboots lol, sounds as a working yet messy workaround! Especially because I wanna edit all the UV maps together and quickly, which will require re-creating dozens of duplicates... It's sad if there is no more robust approach.